# Remove reset entries from git reflog (cleanup)

Tags: git, git-reflog

Is is possible to cleanup repo state so that reset history is removed from reflog?

I did a bunch of reset-hard to find a bug, but then I want to go back to main master state... I mean, I'm kind of at the master state, but reflog remains. Can I cleanup those? Or would I have to re-clone the origin?

```bash
# git reflog
3d4b95d (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD@{10}
99f4098 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD@{8}
056304e HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD@{13}
47b6082 HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to HEAD@{11}
2ab9b26 HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to HEAD@{18}
b6228bd HEAD@{5}: reset: moving to HEAD@{20}
93fd78c HEAD@{6}: reset: moving to HEAD@{6}
99f4098 HEAD@{7}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
99f4098 HEAD@{8}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
99f4098 HEAD@{9}: reset: moving to 99f4098c136787ffb11c5524a334dd999cd805e9
99f4098 HEAD@{10}: reset: moving to 99f4098c136787ffb11c5524a334dd999cd805e9
3d4b95d (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{11}: commit: bootstrap off for now
a53358d HEAD@{12}: reset: moving to HEAD~
93fd78c HEAD@{13}: commit: bootstrap off for now
```

Comment: Why do you want to clean up these entries?

Comment: The reflog (for `HEAD`) is just a text file with one entry per move of `HEAD`. You can remove them manually. But unless there is somehow some sensitive information or something I don't see the need to do that.

Comment: The reflog is *not* supposed to be clean. It's supposed to give a truthful record of what happened. Why the need to have a clean lie rather than the truth? It's not like the list was cluttering something else. Unless you explicitly reach for it, it never shows up.

Comment: I didn't know it's just a single, short file. I wanted to cleanup just in case. I prefer my electronic stuff tidy I guess . @Guildenstern comment answers my question :)